# chromium profile directory is already/used by another BrowserContext instance or process

Tags: jxbrowser

I used an evaluated jxbrowser, which version is 6.14, I write an demo to use it. but i have a problem with it.

Use the demo app to start an application, which can show web UI, keep this applciation with opened, but then I start demo app again, system will throw below exception:
chromium profile directory is already/used by another BrowserContext instance or process

jxbrwowser cannot start two clients in one PC? if can, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

We strongly [recommend](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012878-creating-browser) that you don't use several `BrowserContext` instances with the same profile directory. Chromium engine wasn't designed for such usage and doesn't support it. Even if you don't see any issues right now, the issues will appear later in end user environments. For example, in macOS environment you will get the Chromium's error message dialog every time when you run your application instance developed in such way.

Since it's a critical requirement in the Chromium engine, I don't think we will make it configurable in next versions. This is how Chromium engine works. These is a recommendation we have to follow when working with the Chromium engine.

Comment: how can we use different profile directories for the same java application?

Comment: Please check the article at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012878-creating-browser